# How do the compiler know it is out of scope?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, scope

```
Main()
{
  int i =0;
  ...
  ...
  while(true)
  {
   int k =0;
   ...
   ...
  }
// K is out of scope..
}
```

How does the compiler know K is out of scope?

Comment: Are you asking about how the compiler is implemented, or why the language is designed that way?

Comment: Cause it looks for k and does not find it...

Comment: How does it know when it comes in scope?

Comment: @luqui This is the question one of my friend got in a interview.

Comment: @Sandeep - If the question were asked exactly like that, and a simple answer didn't satisfy them (eg: "The braces denote a block"), I would have told them "magic" and walked out.

Comment: @Ritch my friend said he wanted to slap that guy.. :)

Comment: Try: "Because the compiler's scanner/lexer recognizes the ascii/UTF-8 characters 0x007b and 0x007d and passes them to the parser as tokens to be treated as special with respect to the symbol table stack machine." (Just blow smoke right back at the interviewer :))

Comment: My answer to the interview question would be to ask questions about the question, because it is very unclear right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because as the compiler processes the code it maintains information about each identifier it comes across and each scope it comes across and maintains boundaries for the latter. It knows that K was declared in the while scope and after the scope ends it probably marks the variable as 'no longer in scope' causing any use to be marked as an error.

Answer (score 6):

> How does the compiler know [that a local variable] is out of scope?

First off, let's carefully define the terms you're using. The *scope* of a named entity is *the region of program text in which it is legal to use the name of the entity without additional qualification of the name*.

The scope of a local variable is defined by the specification as the region of program text which is the *entire block* that *immediately* contains the declaration.

The compiler determines the scope of the local variable by keeping track of a *local declaration space* associated with each *syntactic block*. When we need to resolve a name, we figure out what block the name usage is inside, and consult the related declaration space. Of course, blocks nest and so do local variable declaration spaces, so we might have to consult more than one, in order from inside-to-outside.

The actual data structures we use are straightforward hash tables optimized for fast lookup and filtering on various aspects needed by the compiler. (For example, we sometimes need to look up names but only want to get types, or only methods, and so on.)

Does that answer your question? It's a rather unclear question.

Answer (score 1):

`k` is out of scope because the block it was defined in is closed.

Answer (score 1):

I would say it's a meaningless question. K is out of scope because you wrote the program that way: the compiler's *entire function* is to recognize and translate the programming language, including the lexical scope aspect of it.